# Disable LDAP Referral

Tags: windows, active-directory, server, windows-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm currently trying to integrate an SSO with Active Directory. The SSO Service has told me that my server is responding with LDAP "referrals".

Is there a way to disable these referrals? There is only one server/domain, and the server is the domain controller, so I don't know why I would even be getting these in the first place. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you're getting referrals in a single domain forest, I expect something in the SSO app is misconfigured. Perhaps you can provide some more detail on the app, its configuration, and your topology.

Comment: Turns out it was that the "base DN" in the search wasn't specific enough. Apparently you'll get a referral if you don't pinpoint into the exact OU or CN that the user resides. Since I only really have one active OU I just hard-pointed it to there and everything seems to be working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was that the "base DN" in the search wasn't specific enough. Apparently you'll get a referral if you don't pinpoint into the exact OU or CN that the user resides. Since I only really have one active OU I just hard-pointed it to there and everything seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of port 389, use the Microsoft-specific port 3268.

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms808539(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

> Avoid unnecessary SearchResultReference referral chasing
>
> With referral chasing enabled, your code could go from domain to domain in the Active Directory tree trying to satisfy the request if the query cannot be satisfied by the initial domain. This method can be extremely time-consuming. When performing a query for objects and the domain for the objects is unknown, use the global catalog as a base for the search instead of using referral chasing.

then:

> Connecting to the Global Catalog
>
> There are several ways to connect to a global catalog. If you are using LDAP, then use port 3268 in the ldap_open or ldap_init calls.

You may *think* everything is satsified by the initial (only!) domain, but...this is a bureaucracy, and list of 1 thing is still a list.

When you create a Security Group, you can make it Global or Domain Local. If the user belongs to a Global Group, like my case, AD automatically assumes there may be more information to be found in the Global Catalog, so a query to port 389 will generate 3 references. There's probably other reasons references are triggered.

I had to solve this issue because I had many OUs directly below the top level, all of which I wanted to query in one authentication pass.

In particular the mod_ldap.c of ProFTPd was distracted by these referrals.  It followed them in separate LDAP transactions *without* binding with the same credentials as the initial query. Although they added nothing, the ldap library must have returned an opaque error.